# WPF Transformations -- Rotating and switching width/height?

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, rotatetransform, rendertransform

Basically, I have a `FooControl` (I did **not** set the Height/Width explicitly) added to a `Grid`.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <FooControl x:Name="HWFoo" Content="HelloWorld" Grid.Row="0">
        <FooControl.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <RotateTransform Angle="270" />
                <TranslateTransform Y="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=HWFoo}" />
            </TransformGroup>
        </FooControl.RenderTransform>
    </FooControl>
</Grid>
```

But, the problem now is that the FooControl fills up the entire row and when it's transformed it looks quite bizarre (because of it's height/width).

---

FooControl is a custom control. So do I do something with the ArrangeOverride or MeasureOverride? Or am I doing something wrong that can be fixed in XAML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1 - Use LayoutTransform
2 - Set `HorizontalAlignment` to Left or Right to prevent stretching

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <FooControl x:Name="HWFoo" Content="HelloWorld" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <FooControl.LayoutTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <RotateTransform Angle="270" />
                <TranslateTransform Y="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=HWFoo}" />
            </TransformGroup>
        </FooControl.LayoutTransform>
    </FooControl>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'bizarre', but I'd suggest to try and use LayoutTransform instead of RenderTransform - that's probably the issue.

Due note however that LayoutTransform is significantly slower than RenderTransform.

Answer (score 1):

Use **[LayoutTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.layouttransform.aspx)** instead of [RenderTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransform.aspx).

http://patconroy.wordpress.com/2009/03/24/layouttransform-vs-rendertransform-in-wpf/

Simple :)